# Multiple for loop iterators to unpack in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, iteration

I am wondering if it's posiible to iterate over two lists at once.
Something like that:

```
for x, m in list1, list2:
    ...
```

I know that I should use the '.items()', but I don't want to create dictionary from two lists.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
for x, m in zip(list1, list2):
```

> zip(*iterables)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted. With a single iterable argument, it returns an iterator of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty iterator.